# WordPress wp_safe_remote_get() in offline

Tags: wordpress

You must continue executing the code after the wp_safe_remote_get() failed to execute offline.
By default, the wp_safe_remote_get() stops code execution offline.

Answer (score 0):

We get the error not when we try to download the content, but after applying the variable. Before using the downloaded content, you need to check the variable for errors with the is_wp_error() function